# Can't show image in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a panel with items and I also want to add an image to it, here is the code. (Later I add this panel to a new window).

```
var frmCar = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    bodyPadding: 5,
    frame  : true,
    items    :[
        {
            xtype       : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel  : 'Number: ',
            name        : 'number'
        },,
        {
            xtype       : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel  : 'Model: ',
            name        : 'model'
        },{
            xtype       : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel  : 'Image path: ',
            name        : 'image'
        },
        { xtype: 'image',
          width: 200,
          height: 400,
          src: 'c:/image1.jpg'
        }
    ]
});
```

The panel shows all elements - but not the image, what am I doing wrong?
Also I want to let user enter image path - do I then have to replace single path separators with double? e.g. / to this // ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the extJS part looks ok. The problem is probably that you can't access image from your hardrive if you run your page from a webserver.

Try putting your image in a folder that is accessible via HTTP and use a relative URL instead of the filepath. 
Or try to use an image from the internet (like https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)  to test if it show up.

Comment: It seems it worked now - though image got stretched strangely  - how can I set stretching properties? Also last time I managed to set an image which was located in side my project folder. Why this? PS I am running CMD web server

Comment: if you open a html file locally (double clic on the html file for example) you can access file from your file system, but if you access it trough a webserver the access to the filesystem is blocked for security reason.

Comment: Thanks I have different problem I would appreciate. This is my code with that image: http://codepad.org/5GEIKvJi, it opens the window with the image, but when I click the OK button, and then try to open different image, The window is not displayed anymore. Can you please help me what I did wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's because you hide the window in the code from the ok button instead of closing it, which mean the window will not be destroyed.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do?

Comment: try using win.close(); instead of win.hide();

Comment: So can you please explain to me once why once in my app I managed to load an image which was in the same folder as my project -- but I can't load image from C drive ?

Comment: this is a complicated subject far outside the scope of a 600 characters comment :) 
basically the browser behaviour is not the same if you open a file from your hardrive or from an url.

Comment: that 's actually a good question you could ask on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: OK I might do so: but can you at least please tell me if this makes sense for you that I was able once to open an image which was located inside the same project - but I can't open image say from C? Does it make sense to you? No need to explain reason. Just yes or no